# Problem running DemoApp in facebook-ios-sdk

Tags: iphone, facebook

I downloaded the Facebook IOS SDK from http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk, and tried to run the sample/DemoApp.  All functions seemed to run fine, except that I couldn't publish a stream.  The FB dialog (FB box with blue border) just showed that my FB app has a problem.

In the XCode proj, I only filled-in my FB app-id to the DemoAppViewController.m, and DemoApp-Info.plist.

By printing out the URL that the FB dialog actually accessing, I found that the last URL contains the following as the query string (sorry that I didn't have the Mac right now, so everything is from my memory):

error=Invalid+user+id

Has anyone run the demo and succeeded in publishing a stream?

Am I missing anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there was a problem with FB server.  I tried again today and the feed could be published successfully.